# Neutral current in three-phase system when supplying single-phase loads

Tags: voltage

My question is :what is the role of neutral conductor in the 230v European single-phase system .My assumption how it works that a neutral conductor serves to close the circuit between phases and to carry the imbalance current
between different phases  If all the phases are balanced then the neutral conductor does not  caries  the current but closes the circuit  between different phases .?[image]

To be even clearer I have drawn a diagram.  excuse for bad drawing

Comment: The neutral does **not** only conduct the difference of currents. What does the size of a house have to do with this? "tu" is not an English word.

Comment: This probably depends where in the world you are.

Comment: what is the purpose of neutral in 240v single phase system Whether the neutral conductor is used to close the circuit with the other phases and to carry a difference between phase currents .?

Comment: @tor2006: You are still confused. "*... in 240v single phase system ... close the circuit with the other phases ...*" You need to make up your mind. Are you asking about single phase (L + N) or two phase 180° or three-phase 120° systems.

Comment: In 240V single phase system Neutral carries the entire current. Otherwise, an RCD trips and the lights go out.

Comment: In Europe, the former voltages 220 and 240 V were harmonized to 230 V many years ago.

Comment: The title asks about a single phase system, but later you mention multiple phases, and that's also what the diagram seems to be showing.  I might have given some slack to let you fix these things, but with the blatant sloppiness in the title and the text I'm just going to close this mess.

Comment: @Uwe With some variance (obviously). My UPS at home reports 236 V AC on the mains right now. I have regularly seen it go slightly above 240 V indicated.

Comment: @tor2006: You have two more votes to go before your question is closed as "unclear what you are asking". Read the comments above carefully and then fix your question. You should have done this in your edit five hours ago. In particular fix your single / three-phase confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The neutral is made locally by transformers. The high voltage power lines don't carry them. Neutral is attached to earth here for safety. There are local transformer buildings in the neighborhood. No pole mounted transformers in the Netherlands at least.

The neutral serves a purpose of providing 230V while still keeping the option to use 400V for electric stoves or power equipment (eg: drills, lathes).
In the socket only one wire is live for safety, instead of two lives referenced to earth.
We thought two lives was a good idea back in the early days, but proved to be unsafe for residential use.

Normal households with a three phase connection will have their electrical system spread over all three phases. Typically with 3x 25A/35A main breaker and GFCI per four 16A breakers.

I believe the US has a similar option with 120V to neutral and 208V between phases.
Not that different, except the use of electric kettles and stoves is easier.

Comment: 3x 25-35 A main fuses? $HOLYTHING. I've got 3x 16 A main service fuses, and I think most of the breaker panel fuses are 10 or 16 A, and I've never been close to legitimately tripping those.

Comment: 3 x 16 A sounds a bit low. Standard single-phase domestic supply in Ireland is 63 A.

Comment: 3x25A or 25A is the **main breaker**, you will have lower 1x <16A breakers following this. We have 1x35A _fuse_ at home. You can even get 3x65A at home, if you pay.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is :what is the role of neutral conductor in the 230 V European single-phase system. My assumption how it works that a neutral conductor serves to close the circuit between phases and to carry the imbalance current between different phases If all the phases are balanced then the neutral conductor does not caries the current but closes the circuit between different phases?

If currents in the three phases are balanced then at the neutral point they sum to zero. The neutral current is then zero.

If there is an imbalance the difference is carried by the neutral.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKGuy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) With balanced loads the star point is in the geometric centre of the phases even without a neutral connection. (b) In this case L1 is lightly loaded (high resistance) and because there is no neutral connection the star point is "pulled" by the other two phases.*

In an unbalanced circuit without a neutral the 'star' or 'wye' point will move from the centre and the phase-star voltages will vary from their correct operating point. The higher loaded phases will experience a voltage drop. The lightly loaded phases will see a voltage rise.